Is a chi squared test appropriate for this contingency matrix?
I have the following contingency matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    420      & 6750  \\
    150      & 460
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Here the rows stand for apples and bananas, the columns stand for "tasty" and "not tasty":

I'm supposed to find out if there exists a relation between a fruit being an apple/ banana and the fruit being tasty/ not tasty.
I tried doing this using a chi squared test, however, the chi squared I calculated for this is very high $\left(290.54\right)$ and with one degree of freedom this results in a $p$ value of essentially $0$, indicating that there indeed exists a relation.
However, this sounds a bit strange to me, as the $p$ value is extremely low.
I was thus wondering if a chi squared test is even appropriate here.
I know that a chi squared test is inappropriate if many of the expected values in the cells are less than $5$, but this is not the case here since I calculated the expected values as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    525.12 & 6644.88 \\
    44.88 & 565.12
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I mean, the comparison between these two matrices indeed suggests some kind of relation, as for example only $\sim 7\ \%$ of bananas are expected to be tasty while $\sim 25\ \%$ percent of all bananas are tasty, but still this doesn't look to me sufficiently strong to justify a $p$ value of zero?
Maybe there's an issue with the fact that way more apples than bananas have been tested?

Are there any better options than a chi squared test?

for the contingency tables/matrices it would be better to show them as tables with labels on the columns and rows directly in the figure instead of explaining those labels in the text.

"this doesn't look to me sufficiently strong to justify a p
value of zero?" The p-value is not zero, instead it is too small to be computed. Also, it is only a theoretical computation based on a model. It doesn't include potential experimental failures that could have been made. (e.g. one research assistant switching the columns because you didn't tell which one refers to tasty or not tasty).

Is this a homework question? Those numbers seem made up. What kind of test with bananas are such that only 7% are tasty?

There is nothing wrong using a $\chi^2$ in this case, and there is nothing wrong with your calculation. The p-value is indeed 0. Yes, it is very low, as it should be. One proportion is 5.9%%, the other 24.6%. Almost 4 times more!. And it is not as if your sample size is small; you "tested" almost 8000 fruits; a lot less apples, but still 600. With this number of observations, such a difference in proportion is way beyond plausible, under the null of equal proportions.
Yes, there are alternatives (e.g. Fisher-exact). There are also flavors of the $\chi^2$ test, e.g. with Yates correction (to give normal approximation results much closer to Fisher). There is even a  G-test (another normal approximation). But in your case, with such a large difference, with large number of observations, they will all return p-values of essentially $0$.
If you want to double check your calculations, you can plug in your numbers in this very good and thorough online $\chi^2$ calculator, or this one, which computes Fisher exact and $\chi^2$, with and w/o Yates.
The only nit I would pick (and it is a (very?) small one), is that most often, the "treatment" or groups (in your case the type of fruit) are in the columns, and the categories (in your case tasty/not tasty) are in the rows. It is far from being universal, but it is the most common presentation. Of course, it does not change the results.

You are (if you don't mind my saying) overthinking this.
That it doesn't look particularly strong to you is because of your lack of familiarity with significance tests.
When a test doesn't give a response that you expect, your first reaction should not be to try to do another test.
The answer is correct, the chi-square test is appropriate.
